# Get Response Data in XML format in IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Tags: c#, response, restsharp, xml-deserialization

I am using restsharp client to execute the restful API. I want to get response data in XML format while executing the restful API.

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

API returns the 'XML' format. Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: If the API returns XML then everything is ok, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Heinz.
Yes, That's correct. API should return the XML.
Please go through my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Need to add the header parameter in the request. Please see the below code.

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
```